# How to upload a file to Google drive with Service Account using a proxy (host ,port )?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm currently working on a Python script to upload files to Google Drive using a Service Account. The script is functional, **but I need to make it work through a proxy server**.

Here's the code I'm using for uploading files to Google Drive using Service Account:

```
import os
import googleapiclient.http
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_file_location = 'service_account.json' # path to json file 

def upload_file(service, file_path, folder_id):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    file_metadata = {
        'name': file_name,
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }
    media = googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload(file_path)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print(f'File uploaded with ID: {file["id"]}')

def main():
    # Get the service account credentials from json file 
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_file_location)
    
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    
    cho = "y"
    while cho == "y":

        file_to_upload_path = input("Enter the path to the file you want to upload: ")
        
        folder_id = input("Enter the ID of the Google Drive folder where you want to upload the file: ")

        upload_file(service, file_to_upload_path, folder_id)
        
        cho = input("Do you want to upload another file? (y/n): ")
```

I know that googleapiclient library uses httplib2 as its underlying network client, and **httplib2** supports the standardized **HTTP_PROXY** and **HTTPS_PROXY** environment variables

***But how do I upload the file using a proxy server***

I've searched for solutions online but haven't found clear instructions for integrating a proxy server into this specific use case. Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!!

Comment: does this give you an idea? : [Has anyone had this issue when using a proxy within Google Drive/PyDrive upload function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72033500/has-anyone-had-this-issue-when-using-a-proxy-within-google-drive-pydrive-upload). 
You have to set up the proxy information when you create httplib2 object.

Comment: @Twilight I already tried setting up the proxy information when creating the httplib2 object but it just dosent work , and link you shared is using Oauth2 while i am using a service account